# Can you rename a chrome window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension where I let the user select tabs and open them in a new window. I can do so by making use of `chrome.windows.create()`. I know you can manually rename the window in chrome but I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/) that allows you to rename it in js? So is it possible to rename windows in js?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whP06.png)

Comment: do you mean `document.title()`

Comment: `document.title = "Doesn't this work?"`

Comment: It renames the popup in my extension where my code is. Can I rename the active chrome window with all the tabs?

Comment: Use `document.title` in content scripts in all the tabs you want renamed

Comment: I want to rename the whole window (see image) not the tabs themselves.

Comment: If you're referring to the `Right click -> Name Window`, probably not. It seems to be a rather new feature and there's no mention of it in the extension api docs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `is it possible to change site title`? If that's what u want u - can use document.title = "new site name".

Comment: How would I specify the window I want to rename?